# Free 3 of 9 code is not showing Barcode format on mozila,IE browser

Tags: c#-4.0, barcode-scanner

I am going to generate a barcode by `Free 3 of 9` font.Every thing is working fine but when i open my generated html file then it shows me text not in barcode format.If i try to convert `*1*` into barcode then it just show me `*1*` in html file.It is showing good in IE 9 but not in IE 10 and even not in Mozila.

Code:

```
StringBuilder lines = new StringBuilder();
            lines.Append("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd>' <html>");
            lines.Append("<body>");
            lines.Append("<span style='font-family: Free 3 of 9; font-size:36px'>*1*</span>");
            lines.Append("<br><span>Peter Jones</span>");
            lines.Append("<br><br><br>");
            lines.Append("</body>");
            lines.Append("</html>");
            File.WriteAllText(".\\BarCodeFile.htm", lines.ToString());
            Process.Start(".\\BarCodeFile.htm");
```

I tried with `Code 128` as well but it does not work.
I tried hard but unable to find my mistake.So please help me where i am wrong.

Website from where i download [Free 3 of 9 Font](http://www.barcodesinc.com/free-barcode-font/)

Comment: even i have got the same issue, im using Asp.Net MVC3, this Free 3 of 9 code is working fine in my SSRS solution, but when i use it in my Views it simply does not work. Simple text is shown rather than the barcode style. Please anyone suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and putting the font name into single quotes solved my problem.
For example:-

```
style="font-family:'Free 3 of 9';font-size:65px;"
```